# pthread_sigmask on Android not working?

Tags: android, android-ndk

It appears that pthread_sigmask does not work on Android. The issue seems to have been reported 2 years back [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15337) but there has been no response from developers. I am running into a very similar issue (my code below for reference). Am I doing something wrong, or is it an issue with Android NDK? And any tips/help on how I can use two threads with handling of a particular signal restricted to a thread?

I am running this code on Android 2.2.

```
// block the signal in this thread
sigset_t signals;
sigemptyset(&signals);
sigaddset(&signals, SIGALRM);
int ret = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &signals, NULL);
if (ret) {
    LOG("pthread_sigmask failed. %d", ret);
}
```

I am getting an error 22 (EINVAL). I am getting the same error for SIG_UNBLOCK too.

Update: Looks like it works on 4.1 devices. I tried on a 4.1 and it seems to succeed. It failed on 2.3 and 4.0 devices as well.

Any hints on how to ensure signal handler for a particular signal runs on only one thread? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the implementation was fixed here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/9bf330b5676d0f60b3e4c3b8985494bcb1134e8b

You may be able to use sigprocmask() instead, though the behavior isn't officially defined for multi-threaded processes.

Comment: sigprocmask is useless since my program is a multi-threaded one. But thanks for the info anyway.

Comment: for those that need to use this function on Android-15 or previous, there is a workaround here: 

http://www.nadavos.com/patch-nodejs-to-run-on-android-4-04/